# c# application excel vsto conditional formatting

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a VSTO c# application and I am trying to apply conditional formatting so when the value in Column V is set to No make the whole row grey. headercount variable is my last column number

```
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition format7 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition)(uiWorksheet.get_Range("B7:Z" + headercount,
  Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
  "V=No", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));
        format7.Interior.Color = true;
```

I tried the below but it doesnt work - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using Excel's `INDIRECT` function with the conditional formatting triggered by the `Application.SheetChange` event. Please note that the internal quotation marks for the formula need to be escaped.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition format7 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition)(uiWorksheet.get_Range("B7:Z" + headercount,
Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
"=INDIRECT(\"V\"&ROW())=\"No\"", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));

format7.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
```